# Best way to convert data to HTML Objects

Tags: javascript

Which is better and why?

```
var x = DOMParser().parseFromString(data, "text/html").body.firstChild;
var y = Object.assign(document.createElement("x"), {innerHTML: data}).firstChild;
```

Comment: Better is not a testable requirement. What do you consider better? Safer, faster, less error prone, etc?

Comment: So which one of safer or faster isn't better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should *not* use the `createElement` method if the source data is untrustworthy, because inline handlers (like `onerror`) can be invoked when setting `innerHTML`:

```js
const data = `<img src="badsrc" onerror="console.log('evil')"></img>`;

// OK:
console.log('about to use DOMParser');
var x = new DOMParser().parseFromString(data, "text/html").body.firstChild;

// Potentially unsafe:
console.log('about to use createElement');
var y = Object.assign(document.createElement("x"), {innerHTML: data}).firstChild;
```

Comment: Could the downvoter explain? I'm *pretty sure* avoiding malicious code execution is not opinion-based.

Comment: instead of innerHTML, you can use innerText, 
I am NOT the downvoter

Comment: @AshokMandal Assigning to `innerText` (or to `textContent`) will not set any child nodes, except for a single text node - using that method won't help with navigating through an HTML string. (for example, with that, it wouldn't be possible to get the `badsrc` from the snippet above)

Comment: Given inner data is supposed ,just to render text

Comment: Sure, but OP isn't trying to render anything, OP is trying to *parse* HTML.

Comment: The objects craeted would be added to the DOM at some point, but IMHO @CertainPerformance did show a reason to select one of the options as better than the other.